# How to detect a change in the contents of a HTML element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am using `Ruby on Rails` `3.1.0` and the `jquery-rails` gem. I would like to bind a jQuery event (maybe I could use the `live` functionality...) to a HTML `div` tag so that I can check its content changes and, if so (that is, if new code is added to the that `div` tag), to create a custom text in another HTML `div` tag.

That is, in my view file I have:

```
<div id="div_content_1"></div>

<div id="div_content_2"></div>
```

I would like to add\remove an "Hello!" text message inside the `div` with `id="div_content_2"` eachtime the `div` *content* with `id="div_content_1"` changes (in my case, when an HTML `input` field is added to that `div` tag - read the example that follows). For example (in the "add" case), when the `div` with `id="div_content_1"`changes like this

```
<div id="div_content_1">
  <!-- The following 'input' tag was just added -->
  <input ... />
</div>
```

I would like to make it to work so to have an output like the following in the `div` with `id="div_content_2"`:

```
<div id="div_content_2">
  <p>
    Hello!
  </p>
</div>
```

**How can I do that?**

*P.S.*: I am implementing a form for which a user, after selecting some option (this event is intended to generate HTML `input` fields in the `div` with `id="div_content_1"` - I make that for my custom purposes...) can order those option on the same page (the `div` with `id="div_content_2"` is intended to make possible the sorting process that I planned).

Comment: Why don't you just have you DOM-modifying code do this? It's a bit overkill to do this.

Comment: jQuery doesn't have any built-in way to do what you are wanting. The most common way to achieve this cross-browser is with a setInterval checking the contents of the div for changes every x milliseconds. I think the livequery plugin handled this, but i'm not sure. I never use that kind of logic, it is better to trigger a custom event manually when you add the content.

Comment: Not true Kevin.  jQuery doesn't have a completely cross-browser* way to do what he wants.  See my answer.

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
$('#div_content_1').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
    $('#div_content_2').html('<p>Hello</p>');
});
```

Working example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8m7JM/1/)

This method is better than the other two because it does not use polling.  Instead, it uses the Observer pattern, which is much better.  However, the downside is that this won't work in versions of Internet Explorer lower than 9.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
($.fn.watchChanges = function(cb){
    $(this).each(function(i, e){
        $(e).data("original_content", $(e).html());
        window.content_changes = window.content_changes ? window.content_changes : [];
        window.content_changes.push({"element": e, "callback": cb});
    });
    return $(this);
})(jQuery);

setInterval(function(){
    if(window.content_changes)
    {
        $.each(window.content_changes, function(i, e) {
            if($(e.element).data("original_content") != $(e.element).html())
            {
                e.callback.apply($(e.element));
                $(e.element).data("original_content", $(e.element).html())
            }
        });
    }
}, 500);
```

Usage:

```
$('.foo').watchChanges(function(){
    $('.bar').html("something's different about you, foo!");
});
```

Comment: I think that your approach is too much effort for what I need to make. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a "duh" kind of answer, but honestly I think your best bet is to simply modify your "change the DIV" function so that it calls another function:

```
function addInputToDiv(newInput) {
    div1.append(newInput);
    takeSomeActionToDiv2InResponse();
}
```

This isn't as cool as using crazy events like DOMSubtreeModified ... but it will work in all browsers.