# How to detect when content of a span element changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Lets say I have `span` as follows `<span id='myId'>content before change</span>`

I need an event something like

```
$('#myId').contentChanged(function(){
   alert( 'New content: ' + $(this).text() )
})
```

So when I change the content of the span as follows

`$('#myId').text('content after change')`

the `contentChanged` event above fires. It should be rather efficient performance wise, because in my case there could be hundreds of them being monitored.

Comment: Have you looked at using an MVVM framework, such as KnockoutJS or AngularJS?  Knockout in particular allows you to have "subscribers" that are notified when a DOM node bound to a ViewModel changes.  Here is a live example using Knockout: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/QREf3/  and here is a link with more detail:http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/reacting-to-changes-in-knockoutjs.html

Answer (score 2):

You may try like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
     $('#myId').bind( "contentchange", function(){
          alert("Changed");
    });

    $( "#btn" ).click( function () {
        $('#myId').html( "Value" ).trigger( "contentchange" );
    });
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RKLmA/192/)**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I cannot trigger `contentchange` myself. Content is being changed without my control.

Comment: @celalo:- How about trying to add a handler for [DOMCharacterDataModified](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-MutationEvent) and also check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FMutation_events

Comment: @celalo:- Are you looking for something like this:- http://jsfiddle.net/GJCgv/28/

Comment: I was trying to avoid interval checks for performance concerns. I thought maybe there could be a native DOM event to handle this case more efficiently.

Comment: @celalo:- Did you checked the fiddle which I just added in the comments. That would not require the trigger()

Comment: Do you mean this one? http://jsfiddle.net/GJCgv/28/ It has a trigger in the code. Am I looking for something else?

Answer (score 1):

You could create an interval to check for change:

```
function monitorElementText(selector) {
    var $el = $(selector);
    $el.data("elementText", $el.text());

    setInterval(function() {
        if ($el.data("elementText") != $el.text()) {
            $el.trigger("change");
            $el.data("elementText", $el.text());
        }
    }, 50);

    return $el;
}
```

And implement it as such:

```
monitorElementText("#span1").on("change", function() {
    alert( 'New content: ' + $(this).text() );
});
```

It would likely not be good to have a big number of these running. But if you are only monitoring a few elements, it could work for you.

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a proper solution, but I am hesitant to use interval checks for performance concerns. I might need to check for several dozens of them.

Comment: Agreed. But I don't know of any JS events that would handle the event the way you need at the browser level.

Comment: @celalo: Here is a similar SO article. Not sure if it works on text content changes and it apparently has some browser version limitations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690817/how-to-detect-a-change-in-the-contents-of-a-html-element

Answer (score -1):

`MutationObserver` allows you to monitor DOM nodes. Actual code would depend on your specific situation, refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver. Keep in mind that for older browsers you’re gonna have to implement it with deprecated `MutationEvent`s, but they are nevertheless better from performance POV than timers.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I will dig into this topic and see if I can manage to utilize them.